# Android : Loading Images URI returning null

Tags: android, uri

i have an gallery app its working fine for me and i am seeing weird crashes on Crashlaytic this is logs

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
   at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
   at java.io.File.(File.java:134)
   at com.*****.*****.adapters.AlbumsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AlbumsAdapter.java:94)
   at com.*****.*****.adapters.AlbumsAdapter.onViewRecycled(AlbumsAdapter.java:34)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6508)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6541)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5484)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5750)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5589)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5585)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2231)
   at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:556)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1518)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:610)
   at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3719)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3436)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3988)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15679)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5061)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15679)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5061)
```

and this is my line where i am getting this crash this is my `onBindViewHolder` method

```
 request = GlideApp.with(context)
            .asDrawable()

            .centerCrop()
            .override(reqWidth, reqWidth)
            .transition(withNoTransition());

  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Utilities.setMaxLines(holder.img_label);


    Log.i("times", "times");

    AlbumClass item = list.get(position);
    if (item.getType() == Utilities.TYPE_VIDEOS) {
        if (item.bitmap != null)
            holder.gallery_img.setImageBitmap(item.bitmap);
    } else {

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(item.getFilePath()));

        request.load(uri).into(holder.gallery_img);
    }
    //holder.gallery_img.setImageBitmap(Utilities.getImageBitmap(type, mContext, item.getFirstChildId()));
    holder.img_label.setText(item.getName());
    holder.count.setText(String.valueOf(item.getCount()));


}
```

can someone please help why this is happening ?
[image]

Comment: Looks like `item.getFilePath()` is returning null.

Comment: Why don't you just use file  path for loading image ? Check for path to contain a valid URL.

Comment: I also agreed with @MikeM. Please check null condition before accessing item.getFilePath().

Comment: Your image file path getting null value. Please Log your file path before request.

Comment: Actually this gallery locker app and i save all the information in model  from `ContentResolver` later i get these paths from there

Comment: Not everything you get via `ContentResolver` will be a file with a local file path. A `ContentProvider` can serve up pretty much any kind of content it wants; e.g., BLOBs from a database, media from over the network, etc. You need to account for that.

Comment: `String[] PROJECTION_BUCKET = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID,

                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE};


        String BUCKET_GROUP_BY = "1) GROUP BY 1,(2";

        String BUCKET_ORDER_BY = "MAX(datetaken) DESC";
Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(getUriOfType(type), PROJECTION_BUCKET,BUCKET_GROUP_BY, null, BUCKET_ORDER_BY);` 
i am getting images like this

Comment: I'm pretty sure Glide can handle content URIs. Why don't you just use those, instead of trying to get file paths for every item?